# Share Point 2010 Content By Query Web Part (ddwrt:FormatDate)

Tags: xml, xslt, sharepoint, web-parts

I made a few changes to the XSL file to change how my data is displayed. I am  fetching `@Created` to display on the new custom template.- this works so far.

Now, I am trying to change the format to `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` using `<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(@Created, 2057, 3)"/>`

However, for this to work, I have to add `xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime` to the beginning on the XSL file which requires internet access.

This server does not have internet access and never will.. is there a different way to change date-time format?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try saving the schema locally and using the [schemaLocation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256100(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute to reference the local file for your schema validation.

For example, you might end up with something like

```
    xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime"   
xmlns="ddwrt" xsi:schemaLocation="ddwrt c:\locallocation\schema.xsd"
```

Comment: I'll give that a try tomorrow morning.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

apparently , it does not matter as it just needs the namespace.

1) add this entry at the beginning of the file within the section `<xsl:stylesheet ...>:`

```
xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime
```

2) Declare the format where you want the data transformation with the value to transform. In my case @Created:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(@Created, 2057, 3)">
```

3) Save the file and publish the changes.